# heroku_herocutter - undefined method `list' for class `Heroku::Command::Plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to install [Heroku Herocutter](https://github.com/hone/heroku_herocutter)

When running:

```
$ heroku plugins:install git://github.com/hone/heroku_herocutter.git
ERROR: Unable to load plugin heroku_herocutter: undefined method `list' for class `Heroku::Command::Plugins'

/Users/xxxx/.heroku/plugins/heroku_herocutter/lib/heroku_herocutter.rb:26:in `install': undefined method `fetch_git_uri' for #<Heroku::Command::Plugins:0x1020eed10 @options={}, @args=[]> (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:117:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:117:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/bin/heroku:14
    from /usr/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:19
```

Suggestions? Thanks